# RESTful Access of Flask Endpoint

Tags: python, json, rest, flask, postman

I'm trying to create a RESTful endpoint in my flask app, however when I try to hit the endpoint it returns: `TypeError: organize() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)`. I am using `Postman` in chrome to send the request and I have included all parameters as `form-data`.

Code:

```
@app.route('/organize', methods = ['POST'])
def organize(request):
    salary = request.form['salary']
    monthly_expenses = 0.0

    ### Get city/state from zip or (if provided) just proceed
    try:
        zipcode = request.form['zipcode']
        citystate = zippo(zipcode)
        citystate = json.loads(citystate)
        city = citystate['city']
        state_abbr = citystate['state_abbr']

    except DoesNotExist:
        city = request.form['city']
        state_abbr = request.form['state']

    ### Car stuff
    paymentsbool = request.form['paymentsbool']
    try:
        cartype = request.form['cartype']
        payments = request.form['payments']
        insurance_year = request.form['insurance']
        insurance = insurance_year / float(12)
    except DoesNotExist:
        trans = request.form['trans']

    ### Cell phone stuff
    cellbool = request.form['cellbool']
    try:
        cell = request.form['cell']
        monthly_expenses = monthly_expenses + cell
    except DoesNotExist:
        pass

    ### Living expenses
    rent = request.form['rent']
    nat = request.form['nat']
    cable = request.form['cable']
    gas = request.form['gas']
    elec = request.form['elec']
    groceries = request.form['groceries']

    monthly_sal = salary / float(12)
    monthly_sal_af_tax = monthly_sal * .72
    monthly_savings = monthly_sal_af_tax * .15

    if request.form['carbool'] == True:
        car_month = car(cartype, payments, insurance)
        monthly_bal = monthly_bal - car_month
        transportation = car_month
    else:
        monthly_bal = monthly_bal - trans
        transportation = trans

    monthly_expenses = monthly_expenses + rent + nat + cable + gas + elec + groceries + transportation
    monthly_bal = monthly_sal_af_tax - monthly_savings - monthly_expenses

    return jsonify(monthly_bal = monthly_bal, transportation = transportation, monthly_sal_af_tax = monthly_sal_af_tax, monthly_savings = monthly_savings, monthly_expenses = monthly_expenses)

def car(type, payments, insurance):
    gas_price = 4.00
    cars = {1:10, 2:15, 3:20}
    tank = cars[type]
    gas_month = 2.00 * tank * gas_price
    car_total = gas_month + payments + insurance

    return car_total
```

I was also wondering if you using `jsonify` to return the data was the best way to do that? Thanks for your help, it is greatly appreciated.

EDIT:
I've also tried hitting the endpoint with `curl` but it returns the same result.

```
curl -X POST -d {‘zipcode’:13905, ‘paymentsbool’:0, ‘trans’:10, ‘cellbool’:0, ‘rent’:20, ‘nat’:30, ‘cable’:40, ‘gas’:50, ‘elec’:60, ‘groceries’:70} http://127.0.0.1:8080/organize --header "Content-Type:application/json"
```

EDIT2: Continuing to play around with this I have removed the `request` parameter so that the function takes no arguments. When I try the `curl` call now it returns

```
<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket at pos 19
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

I could not begin to explain why this was the case but I've discovered that by using `request.values` instead of `request.form` it is able to access the data being sent.

I would still love an explanation as to why `request.form` wasn't working but this did solve my problem.